# Similar matrices problem

Tags: matrices

For what values of a and b are the matrices?
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & a\\ 1&0&b\\ 0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\0&0&-2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I got as far as finding out that $a=-2$. But I cannot figure out $b$. I was given a hint:  this problem is trickier than it seems. After you find potential values for a and b, try to diagonalize $A$. I have tried to diagonalize but it doesn't seem to work. How can I solve for $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues. So just find the characteristic equation of $A$, and then since $B$ is diagonal, you already have the eigenvalues of $B$. Substitute these into the characteristic equation of $A$ and you will get two equations with two unknowns. Solving this will give you the answer...I get $a=-2$ and $b=3$.

Now the trick comes in, since $A$ is not diagonalizable with those values of $a$ and $b$, $A$ cannot be similar to $B$. So the answer is, there are no values of $a$ and $b$ for which the given matrices are similar.